# C - How to add three numbers?

Tags: c

so I've written some codes to add two numbers in C, but I can't figure out how to add three instead without spilling the results into another variable or clobbering the caller's version of the variables?

```
int add(a,b,c)
    int a, b, c;
{   int tempr;
    for(;b--;++a); // danger
    /*tempr = c+a;*/
    tempr = a+c;
    return (tempr);
}
```

Comment: `a+b+c`. Also, the variables hold junk values when you don't initialize them.

Comment: Everything that could be wrong with this code, is wrong.

Comment: I like the tags.

Comment: Flagging as very low quality.

Comment: You probably needs to start with some good `c` books.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how, if you must use a function for some reason.

```
int add(int a,int b,int c) {
    return a+b+c;
}
```

When you define a function in C, you have to define the type of the parameters as well.

Please note the following:

- It is an error to define a variable in a function that has the same name as a function parameter
- Although not an error, there's no need for parentheses when calling `return (tempr);`. 
  `return tempr;` is perfectly fine
- if you use a for loop, ending it with `;` immediately after the `for` statement will result in the following statement not being a part of the loop. This might not be what you had in mind.

Comment: The first version was funnier and to the point, still, I don't know what else could be said about this question. hahahah